# Регулярное выражение на ограничение количества символов в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9+_]{1,64})([\.-][a-zA-Z0-9+_]+)*@([a-z0-9а-я]{1,63}([\.-]([a-z0-9а-я]){1,63})*\.[a-z0-9а-я]{1,63})$
```

Нужно поправить его, пытался сделать так, чтобы вся строка ограничивалась 64-символами, но не выходит.

Comment: ругуляркой ограничение в длине?...либо напишите что еще дорлжна она делать..либо юзайте if(str.length < 64)....

Comment: Эта регулярка должна ограничивать количество символов в input (там ввод почты). Максимум 64 символа, вот

Comment: а для чего это ваше выражение вообще?

Comment: var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9+_]{1,64}([\.-][a-zA-Z0-9+_]+)*@([a-z0-9а-я]{1,63}([\.-]([a-z0-9а-я]){1,63})*\.[a-z0-9а-я]{1,63})$/;

Регулярное выражение, которое ограничивает количество символов в input'е для ввода почты

Comment: тогда это какие весьма специфические адрес почты видимо. ибо даже `test@example.com` не пропускают

Comment: Такого типа пропускает
mail_mail_example_examlpe_mail.rumail_mail_example_examlpe@mail.ru

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^(?=.{1,64}$)тут-остальное-выражение
```

А вообще, не надо издеваться на email'ом.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @Morozh, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от соответствующего ответа.

Comment: @Morozh, а ещё ты букву `ё` забыл.

Comment: Да, проблема решена, отметил, спасибо большое ещё раз!

Answer (score 1):

1) email

2) максимум 64 символа

```html
<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="64">
```

Comment: Нужно именно этим регулярным выражением, я пытался его поправить, но оно почему-то не хочет ограничивать, хотя стоят квантификаторы {1,64-63}

Comment: @Morozh ваши квантификаторы ограничивают каждую часть а не целиком.

Comment: Не подскажите, как ограничить целиком?